# sum times with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Trying to add to times but deprecation warnings as result:

```js
var one = new moment('00:00:01.000', 'HH:mm:ss.SSS');
var two = new moment('00:00:03.002', 'HH:mm:ss.SSS');
var tot = one.add(two);
console.log(tot);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What warnings are you getting? I don't see any.

Comment: @TiiJ7 if you use moment 2.17.1 you will get a warning :)

Comment: Thanks to all you! Problem was version 2.17.1, update to 2.27.0 and work like a charm.Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Before version 2.8.0, the moment#add(String, Number) syntax was also supported. It has been deprecated in favor of moment#add(Number, String).

```
moment().add('seconds', 1); // Deprecated in 2.8.0
moment().add(1, 'seconds');
```

[Moment.js man](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/)

Comment: I would sum var one + var two, as I try to show at my post.

Comment: You add up two timestamps, so result of your question code snippet is `"2071-03-29T18:00:04.002Z"`... Is this what you want to achieve?